# Test a Form with no client side validation

Tags: test-design

I have a long form ~22 fields with no client side validation, and it gives an error message which just reads "Error", after i hit the submit button? how can i go about testing it? any suggestions.

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. If you observe that it just reads "Error", then I assume you are already testing it, right? How do you test other form fields with a Submit button?

Comment: I think developer have put common alert message "Error" when you click on submit button without fill mandatory field or put invalid data.Is this something you facing?

Comment: ok, let me make it more clear. As a user you come to a page with ~22 form fields, you fill them out, none of the field gives you any error(it has no client side validation). But when you submit the form you get error, the error is not specifying which field's input is wrong.How would you know what is wrong here? would you test each of the 22 fields individually?

Comment: You should tell to developer to provide field related error message with specific text. if you have time then you can test fields individually but if we think as end user perspective then this way to show error is wrong. User should be able to identify easily that which field has error.

Comment: Please add environment details if you want more specific answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, if there is no validation on client side at all, you need to have a proper error message why it is failing. So report it as a bug or improvement.
Meanwhile, you can check the log files in the server with the hope that there is any useful info there explaining what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Report that it is unusable as user is not given relevant information. This is a serious bug, especially if it is an important form.

If you need to say something more in it's current state, ask for specification on what should be valid values or value combinations for each field. Then test border cases of each field separately and maybe some random other combinations for a good measure.

Answer (score 0):

If the application under test is a web based (unfortunatelly the question is not exact enough), you can get detailed error message from the browsers. Firefox or Chrome can give you a lot info trough developer tools.

In Chrome: Press Ctrl+Shif+I or F12, from Context 
more info here: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

In Firefox: Press F12 or use Firebug Plugin, from context Inspect Element
more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector

Interresting parts to get more details about the error are:

- Network folder - each request is here with its response
- Console folder - it is javascript console, some frontend errors does not do any network request/response
- Cookies folder - sometimes cookie contains important information about transaction/s